# How to handle Swift Result without success or error?

Tags: swift

Swift's `Result` type is great. But what about a situation like "user cancelled login" where, for example, the Facebook SDK gives you no result and no error?

- It's not success, because you haven't logged in
- You can't call failure without an Error
- Having to make your own "fallback" error is one way around this
- Another is:

`extension Optional: Error { }`

Which feels weird and wrong, but lets you do `completion(.failure(nil))`

Is there an idiomatic Swifty way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean about `Cancel` request? Then try this:

```
if (response.error as NSError?)?.code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
   // Do Your stuff
}
```

Comment: This would be a good thing for the Facebook SDK to provide, but unfortunately in this case it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own error type

```
enum LoginError: Error {
    case userCancelled
    ...
}
```

This makes most sense to me to treat it like any other error since, as you say, success is if the user logged in.